# Is there a faster alternative to find() function in MATLAB?

Tags: performance, matlab, find, runtime, montecarlo

I'm running a kinetic Monte Carlo simulation code wherein I have a large sparse array of which I first calculate cumsum() and then find the first element greater than or equal to a given value using find().

```
vecIndex = find(cumsum(R) >= threshold, 1);
```

Since I'm calling the function a large number of times, I'd like to speed up my code. Is there a faster way to carry out this operation?

the complete function:

```
function Tr = select_transition(Fr,Rt,R)

    N_dep = (1/(Rt+1))*Fr; %N flux-rate
    Ga_dep = (1-(1/(Rt+1)))*Fr; %Ga flux-rate

    Tr = zeros(4,1);

    RVec = R(:, :, :, 3);
    RVec = RVec(:);
    sumR = Fr + sum(RVec); %Sum of the rates of all possible transitions
    format long
    sumRx = rand * sumR; %for randomly selecting one to the transitions 
    %disp(sumRx);
    if sumRx <= Fr %adatom addition
        Tr(1) = 0;
        if sumRx <= Ga_dep
            Tr(2) = 10; %Ga deposition
        elseif sumRx > Ga_dep
            Tr (2) = -10; %N deposition
        end
    else
        Tr(1) = 1; %adatom hopping
        vecIndex = find(cumsum(RVec) >= sumRx - Fr, 1);
        [Tr(2), Tr(3), Tr(4)] = ind2sub(size(R(:, :, :, 3)), vecIndex); %determines specific hopping transition 
    end

end
```

Comment: Did you try writing your own function with a `for` loop? If `R` is sufficiently large, this could be faster than computing `cumsum` for all of `R`.

Comment: `find` is probably not your bottleneck, @CrisLuengo is right. Besides of this, the `format long` command has no business there in your function code (in particular not if you call it over and over again). It sets the format of *displayed* numbers in the *command window*. Therefore, it does not affect the calculation at all but you are fiddling with the MATLAB-IDE in each function call.

Comment: Yes, writing a for loop manually makes it a bit faster. Also, Removed "format long". Thanks for the inputs guys.

Comment: @CrisLuengo , max -- Is there any other optimization that you can suggest in order to speed up this code? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If `Rvec` is sparse it is more efficient to extract its nonzero values and the corresponding indexes and apply `cumsum` on those values.

```
Tr(1) = 1;
[r,c,v] = find(RVec); % extract nonzeros
cum = cumsum(v);
f = find(cum >= sumRx - Fr, 1);
Tr(2) = r(f);
sz = size(R);
[Tr(3), Tr(4)] = ind2sub(sz(2:3), c(f));
```

Comment: Yes, Rvec is a sparse vector, but the above code is not working.

Comment: Do you sure that your code is working? Sometimes `find` may return empty results. The problem may be related to that.

Comment: Yes, my code is correctly functional but it's really-really slow. Maybe I can exploit sparsity in some way to make it faster. Thanks.